# How do I change the tint of an ImageButton on focus/press

Tags: android, image, selector, imagebutton, tint

I have an `ImageButton` in my app and I need to change the tint of the image when the button is `pressed/focused`. I have the `ImageButton` set to get its `src` from an XML file which as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- pressed -->
    <item 
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:tint="@color/black"
        android:drawable="@drawable/search"
        />

    <!-- focused -->
    <item 
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:tint="@color/black"
        android:drawable="@drawable/search"
        />

    <!-- default -->
    <item
        android:tint="@null"
        android:drawable="@drawable/search"
        />

</selector>
```

However the tint isn't applied when the `ImageButton` is pressed or focused - the image just displays as normal. The color black is defined as `#000000` as always. Any ideas?

Comment: Hello. I was wondering if you finally found an XML way of solving this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

You can change the tint, quite easily in code via:

```
ImageButton button = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.button_i_want_to_modify);
button.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255)); // White Tint
```

Comment: Works. But I'd like to it via XML if possible (sorry picky).

Comment: Check the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19500039/how-to-use-selector-to-tint-imageview-in-android

Comment: Or use data binding.

Comment: Adding `android:tint="@color/myColor"` worked for me.

Answer (score 26):

Here is how to do it using just xml.
In your drawable folder create a selector. Eg: touch_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- State when a row is being pressed, but hasn't yet been activated (finger down) -->
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/semi_slate" />

    <!-- When the view is "activated".  In SINGLE_CHOICE_MODE, it flags the active row
     of a ListView -->
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:color="@color/semi_slate" />

    <!-- Default, "just hangin' out" state. -->
    <item android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

In my Image view in xml I set the android:tint attribute to the drawable created above.

```
android:tint = "@drawable/touch_selector"
```

The whole code looked like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/poster"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
android:tint="@drawable/touch_selector" />
```

This is an all xml solution, to put tint on an ImageView on press or on active.
Similar can be done for ImageButton

Note that this only works for API level >= 21.

Comment: You also can use it for API lower than 21 with app:tint.

Comment: Don't know what's wrong. After setted this tint, the imageView would become transparent on normal state...

Comment: You also need to set android:tintMode="src_atop"

Answer (score 11):

Finally I have found a solution for API < 21:

```
Button more = (Button) findViewById(R.id.more);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    more.getBackground().setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
} else {
    Drawable wrapDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(more.getBackground());
    DrawableCompat.setTint(wrapDrawable, color));
    more.setBackgroundDrawable(DrawableCompat.unwrap(wrapDrawable));
}
```

May this help someone not to lose 2 hours !

Comment: if you're using drawablecompat you should be able to use it on lower API versions with no issue

Comment: I was using a normal Button with a custom XML layout. DrawableCompat was the only fix up to today that works on pre-API 21.

Comment: See also my other answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31021823/lollipop-progress-bar-tinting for pre-API 21 usage of DrawableCompat.

Answer (score 8):

I found a way to do this in xml (in api 21 and up at least).

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/search"
            android:tint="@color/black"
            />
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/search"/>
</selector>
```

By setting the tint on the bitmap it's possible to reuse the same drawable in xml without having to intercept touches or subclass ImageView or ImageButton.

Once the selector has been created, just apply that as the src of the ImageView or ImageButton.

Comment: Nice catch! please note that the tint attribute on bitmap element prior to API 21 will do nothing -> https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78461

Comment: fyi, this won't work if your drawable is in xml format. Use `<shape />` instead of `<bitmap />` in that case.

Answer (score 3):

```
bt.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        bt.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255)); // White Tint
                        return true; // if you want to handle the touch event
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        bt.clearColorFilter(); // White Tint
                        return true; // if you want to handle the touch event
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

What I'm doing is add a custom button that has the function setColorFilter.

Like this I can use the new button in the xml.

```
public class CustomButton extends Button {

public CustomButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomButton(Context context, AttributeSet attributes) {
    super(context, attributes);
};

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int maskedAction = event.getActionMasked();
    if (maskedAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.argb(150, 155, 155, 155), PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN);
    else if (maskedAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
        getBackground().setColorFilter(null);
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}}
```

and for the ImageButton

```
public class CustomImageButton extends ImageButton {

public CustomImageButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomImageButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int maskedAction = event.getActionMasked();
    if (maskedAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        setColorFilter(Color.argb(150, 155, 155, 155), PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN);
    else if (maskedAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
        setColorFilter(null);
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I noticed there are some requests here for people wanting to know how to do this in XML.  It is actually quite simple.  This can be accomplished using a `layer-list`

Your button's drawable (drawable/some_button.xml):

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/some_button_highlighted" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/some_button_image" />
</selector>
```

And this is the highlighted drawable (drawable/some_button_highlighted.xml)

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/some_button_image"/>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/highlighted_button_color" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Now you can use this in any other xml:

```
...
android:drawable="@drawable/some_button"
...
```

I hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: This just draws a solid square over the drawable, if there was a way to get the second layer to use the previous layer as an alpha mask then this would be cool

Answer (score 1):

You can set color (tint) from xml.

Set `transparent` (`android:background="@null"`) for `background` then use `tint` :

```
<ImageButton
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:tint="@color/Amber_200"
     android:background="@null"
     android:src="@drawable/back_selector" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and I found this solution :

```
logoImage.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
            if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                if (logoImage.isSelected) {
                    logoImage.setColorFilter(context.getColor(R.color.blue_unselect), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
                } else {
                    logoImage.setColorFilter(null)
                }
            } else if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if (!logoImage.isSelected) {
                    logoImage.setColorFilter(null)
                } else {
                    logoImage.setColorFilter(context.getColor(R.color.blue_unselect), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
                }
            } else if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
                if (root.isSelected) {
                    logoImage.setColorFilter(null)
                } else {
                    logoImage.setColorFilter(context.getColor(R.color.blue_unselect), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
                }
            }
            false
        }
```

it's working for me.

Answer (score -3):

As you defined the selector to be the src of the ImageButton Android will AFAIK just take the drawable because that's what matches the type of src. So tint won't be used.

Nevertheless, I had a similar problem: I also tried to use a selector like yours but for the android:tint value of the ImageButton instead of android:src. Of course I omitted the tint values you have in your selector. This would solve your problem, too, because you want to use the same drawable for all states. Curiously I get a NumberFormatException everytime stating that the system was unable to parse 'res/color/tint_selector.xml' (which is indeed my selector) as integer. To be specific my code looks like this:

This is my selector, saved in /res/color/tint_selector.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_pressed="true"
         android:color="#D3D3D3"/> <!-- pressed -->
   <item android:color="#ff000000"/> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

And this is the corresponding ImageButton:

```
<ImageButton android:id="@+id/program_help"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:src="@drawable/symbol"
     android:tint="@color/tint_selector">
</ImageButton>
```

Maybe this helps you a bit although it currently doesn't work.

Comment: Is this compatible with API's less than 21?