# Help with Image Buttons in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

Hey I was wondering how you make it so that when an image button is pushed it changes color to show it was pushed.

DragonFruitActivity.java

```
package com.Dragon_Fruit;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
public class DragonFruitActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ImageButton playbutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.playbutton); playbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.playbuttonselected);
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent(DragonFruitActivity.this, playbutton.class));
            }

            private void setBackgroundResource(int playbuttonselected) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }


});
        ImageButton settingsbutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.settingsbutton); settingsbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent(DragonFruitActivity.this, settingsbutton.class));
            }


});
    }
}
```

So the new Activity should be:

```
package com.Dragon_Fruit;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
public class DragonFruitActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ImageButton playbutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.playbutton); playbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                arg0.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.playbuttonselected);
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent(DragonFruitActivity.this, playbutton.class));
            }


});
        ImageButton settingsbutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.settingsbutton); settingsbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent(DragonFruitActivity.this, settingsbutton.class));
            }


});
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this old post out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024983/how-do-i-change-the-tint-of-an-imagebutton-on-focus-press

Comment: You don't need your own `setBackgroundResource(...)` method, there's one built-in to the `View` class: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource(int)

Comment: ahh, I see where the problem is. This is my mistake: remove the extra method setBackgroundResource, and add `arg0.` before the call to this method in your onClick method: `arg0.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.playbuttonselected);`

Comment: I added what the new activity should be. Does it look correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your [onClick(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener%28android.view.View.OnClickListener%29) method, you can [setBackgroundResource(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource%28int%29)

```
ImageButton playbutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.playbutton); 
playbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
    @Override public void onClick(View arg0) {
        setBackgroundResource(...);
        startActivity(new Intent(DragonFruitActivity.this, playbutton.class));
    }
}
```

(you will also need to define drawable to use as the background color).

Comment: So this is the code for the button in the activity:  ImageButton playbutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.playbutton); playbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(View arg0) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             startActivity(new Intent(DragonFruitActivity.this, playbutton.class));

Comment: so where would setBackgroundResource go?

Comment: before the `startActivity(...)` method is called.

Comment: ImageButton playbutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.playbutton); playbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void setBackgroundResource (int redid) {
   }
         @Override
         public void onClick(View arg0) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             startActivity(new Intent(DragonFruitActivity.this, playbutton.class));

Comment: so like that? But how do I use the background resource to change the color when pushed

Comment: Ok I got that part but how do I actually fill in the setBackgroundResource? is it like @drawable?

Comment: Assuming you have the drawable `res/drawable/mybackground.png`, or something like this, you can access it with `R.drawable.mybackground`. So the method call would be `setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mybackground);`

Comment: Well its not working but I will put my activity code in the question. Could you take a look and see if theres anything wrong. Also, thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 1):

Please use [StateListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList).

Comment: Sorry, but I'm still confused. Do I have to make a new XML layout just for a selector?

Comment: on the view, set the selector as the value of **android:background**

Comment: Wait sooo do I use an XML layout I already have? Sorry if these are dumb questions but I'm knew to this. And what do you mean by view...

Comment: `<ImageButton android:id="@+id/id"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/image"
android:background="@drawable/your_selector"></ImageButton>`

Comment: so all I do is put that in the xml where my buttton is located

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [this](http://blog.androgames.net/40/custom-button-style-and-theme/). You can download that example and replace the `android:drawable` with your images.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is selector http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

Use them to change the image button color.