# Lollipop Progress Bar Tinting

Tags: android, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design, android-theme

I'm on a Lollipop device (MotoG 2014), I read about progress bar tinting, but this is not working...I get the default progress bar color. What am I missing here?

```
<ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:backgroundTintMode="src_in"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:indeterminateTint="#f00" />
```

Many thanks.

Comment: did you get the answer to this I am on lollipop as well and its not working but everyone seems to  be saying API level 21 should work with ProgressTint

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The accepted solution wasn't working for me on pre-Lollipop, but I found this solution to fit all APIs and on top of that, it doesn't use any deprecated code:

**Java solution**

```
// fixes pre-Lollipop progressBar indeterminateDrawable tinting
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

    Drawable wrapDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(mProgressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable());
    DrawableCompat.setTint(wrapDrawable, ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), android.R.color.holo_green_light));
    mProgressBar.setIndeterminateDrawable(DrawableCompat.unwrap(wrapDrawable));
} else {
    mProgressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), android.R.color.holo_green_light), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
}
```

**Kotlin extension**

```
fun ProgressBar.setIndeterminateTintCompat(@ColorInt color: Int) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        val wrapDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(indeterminateDrawable)
        DrawableCompat.setTint(wrapDrawable, color)
        indeterminateDrawable = DrawableCompat.unwrap(wrapDrawable)
    } else {
        indeterminateTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(color)
    }
}

// usage

val desiredColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.myColor)
myProgressBar.setIndeterminateTintCompat(desiredColor)
```

Happy coding !

Comment: This is the easiest solution I found for pre-lollipop devices. Thanks

Comment: Why is everyone missing the question the question is why this is not working on Lollipop as described by the documentation and everyone

Comment: well dear user3701188, once again you'll have to ask Google about that :)

Comment: I think your condition should be `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {` ? I have tested this and it works for me only if the first piece of code is executed for api over 21.

Answer (score 81):

Try changing your `ProgressBar` to this

```
<ProgressBar
android:id="@+id/view_progress"
style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:indeterminate="true"
android:indeterminateTintMode="src_in"
android:indeterminateTint="@color/red"
/>
```

Also you can do it programmaticaly doing this :

```
ProgressBar progressBar;
progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.view_progress);
progressBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.RED, Mode.SRC_IN);
```

### References

[Setting in ProgressBar Tint color](http://https417.blogspot.com.es/2015/02/setting-progressbar-tint-color-for.html)

Comment: @Ninja Haven't tried this yet, but I guess it would have to be `progressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable()` to be in line with the XML sample.

Comment: It looks like `src_in` is the default, so no need to set it

Answer (score 3):

To avoid tinting the `ProgressBar` background as well, you should get a reference to the exact bitmap from the inner `ProgressBar` `LayerDrawable`. This is a hacky way of doing it, but it works.

```
LayerDrawable layerDrawable = (LayerDrawable) progressBar.getProgressDrawable();
Drawable drawable = layerDrawable.getDrawable(2); // The progress bitmap
drawable.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

Comment: This is just what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works well in Android 6.0+, but not for Android 5.1 and before as I have tested on my local Android emulator.

I agree with the explanation of @Skizo-ozᴉʞS, and I've found an [issue report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37035006) in Android Issue Tracker that may refer to this bug.
[See this link.](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/commit/dbc401888d18e8751e9bd749dcdadb17dcb8f8b2)

From the code it seems that using "android:indeterminateTint" only will not take any effects for API < 23.

Comment: Based on this issue report, you could tell that one option for the `indeterminateTint` to work is to also add `android:indeterminateTintMode="src_in"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**change your progress drawable asrequired****/

   Drawable wrapDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(_progress.getIndeterminateDrawable());
   DrawableCompat.setTint(wrapDrawable, ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorOrange));
  _progress.setIndeterminateDrawable(DrawableCompat.unwrap(wrapDrawable));
```