# Change Color of ImageButton on Scrolling?

Tags: java, android, android-imagebutton

I have the following Android ImageButton:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/myButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/my_button"
    android:background="@null" />
```

The button displays a circle image with a transparent plus in the middle. When the user is scrolling I want to change the color of this button based on the offset.

I tried using `setBackgroundColor()` but this is not the correct way of doing it and it does not work. It must be more the tint color I guess.

**How can I change the color of the ImageButton image dynamically?**

Comment: Apply a color filter to the drawable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try an answer by vokilam to a similar question:

```
ImageButton button = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.button_i_want_to_modify);
button.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255)); // White Tint
```

Found here:
[How do I change the tint of an ImageButton on focus/press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024983/how-do-i-change-the-tint-of-an-imagebutton-on-focus-press)