# Android - change send icon's color on ImageButton

Tags: java, android, android-imagebutton

How to change the default color of send icon on this `ImageButton`?

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ImageButton1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send" />
```

[image]

I want to use gray instead of current white color.

Comment: Used `ImageView` and `setColorFilter(GREY)`

Comment: @MD But I want to click on this button, So how to use clickable ImageView ?

Comment: @ why not? [Check this POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024983/how-do-i-change-the-tint-of-an-imagebutton-on-focus-press)

Comment: @afn see my answer bellow.

Comment: Please, use this class, is such more easy. https://github.com/jrvansuita/IconHandler

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Add tint attribute and you can set any color you want. Also you can set android:tintMode attribute (Which says how the color should apply).

```
 <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ImageButton1"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:paddingTop="5dip"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:tint="@color/colorAccent"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send" />
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use colorFilter on image view and can give any color runtime.

```
iv.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_gray),
                PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Comment: what is PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP?

Comment: @afn it is mode of adding color to image or draw able.
check here - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode.html

Answer (score 4):

Add `android:tint` attribute to set the icon colour.

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ImageButton1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:tint="@color/background_red"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send" />
```

Comment: I have tried implementing this for a delete icon, but the red color is faded, am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

**put this image in your drawable folder and then**

save it in drawable as an image

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ImageButton1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@android:drawable/img" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below code to change it programmatically:

```
Drawable drawableTint = DrawableCompat.wrap(getResources()
        .getDrawable(imageResID)).mutate();
DrawableCompat.setTint(drawableTint, 
        ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.colorTint));

yourImageButton.setImageDrawable(drawableTint);
```

Answer (score 1):

download icon put inside drawable folder

[image: Download Icon]

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ImageButton1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/downloded_icon_send" />
```

Answer (score -2):

you can put your costomize image in you drawable then you can use it as image src

Comment: Edit the same answer instead of posting a new one!