# Change imagebutton color using palette

Tags: android

I am creating a view in which I have one `ImageButton` and one `ImageView`, and I want to change its color using image palette. I am getting the color from image but don't know how to set the image color (remember its ImageButton color, not background color).

Here is code that I have tried:

```
    Palette.from(bitmap).generate(new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {

            Palette.Swatch vibrantSwatch2 = palette.getLightVibrantSwatch();

            if (vibrantSwatch2 != null) {
                favourite.setColorFilter(vibrantSwatch2.getBodyTextColor());
                playlist.setColorFilter(vibrantSwatch2.getBodyTextColor());
            }

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give tint using

```
favourite.setColorFilter(vibrantSwatch2.getBodyTextColor(),
                PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

> Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35286182/5962715).