# How to change color of icon in imageButton xamarin android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

In drawble are icon default(black).
I want to change color for these icon.

Comment: is it a vector image? meaning xml file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024983/how-do-i-change-the-tint-of-an-imagebutton-on-focus-press

Comment: It is a png. It not xml file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you not do something like this:

```
ImageView forecastImage = View.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.ForecastImage);
var color = Color.ParseColor("#AE6118"); //The color u want             
forecastImage.SetColorFilter(color);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `android:tint="#ff0000"` to color an image.

Comment: how do i change that Programmatically ?